# Unable to run AWS CLI: "ImportError: cannot import name 'docevents' from 'botocore.docs.bcdoc'"

Tags: linux, command-line, amazon-web-services

New to linux, I just installed AWS CLI alongside Python3 and boto3 but I get this error when I tried running AWS CLI.

```
fdostuni@PG022:~$ sudo ./aws/install
You can now run: /usr/local/bin/aws --version
fdostuni@PG022:~$ aws --version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/aws", line 19, in <module>
    import awscli.clidriver
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/awscli/clidriver.py", line 36, in <module>
    from awscli.help import ProviderHelpCommand
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/awscli/help.py", line 23, in <module>
    from botocore.docs.bcdoc import docevents
ImportError: cannot import name 'docevents' from 'botocore.docs.bcdoc' (/home/fdostuni/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/docs/bcdoc/__init__.py)
```

Comment: This is exactly the situation I have been. But I wanna know why this error happens?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

try running

```
pip3 install --upgrade awscli
```

or

```
pip install --upgrade awscli
```

Comment: ERROR: awsebcli 3.20.3 has requirement botocore<1.24.0,>1.23.41, but you'll have botocore 1.27.57 which is incompatible.
Trying to navigate my way out of this one.

Comment: It is important to note that this will install major version 1 of the `aws` cli. If you want to install `aws` cli version 2, which is recommended by AWS, follow: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/getting-started-install.html

Answer (score 0):

- `pip3 install --upgrade awscli`
- worked
- NOT
- `sudo pip3 install --upgrade awscli`
- You will have a 2 different version if you install it on the system layer versus the directory layer.
- `pip install --upgrade awscli` is yet another set of packages that you will have on your computer. It can get unruly to have so many version of your computer.